# Ruby ternary operator not returning as expected

Tags: ruby

I have following code

```
@services = []
@services << @user.services.where(active: true).blank? ? @user.services.build(active: true) : @user.services.where(active: true).first
```

Instead of returning service object I get true or false in the array. Why is that?

Comment: Operator precedence maybe. Try putting parentheses around the ternary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in this [precedence table](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html), `<<` is higher than `?`, so your code is parsed as :

```
(@services << @user.services.where(active: true).blank?) ? @user.services.build(active: true) : @user.services.where(active: true).first
```

You could write :

```
@services = []
@services << (@user.services.where(active: true).blank? ? @user.services.build(active: true) : @user.services.where(active: true).first)
```

But it's not very readable, and you call `where` twice.

```
active_services = @user.services.where(active: true)
service = if active_services.blank?
            @user.services.build(active: true)
          else
            active_services.first
          end
@services = [service]
```

**Update** From @mudasobwa's excellent comment :

```
@services = [@user.services.where(active: true).first || @user.services.build(active: true)]
```

**Update** From @Stefan, it looks like your code is equivalent to :

```
@services = [@user.services.find_or_initialize_by(active: true)]
```

Comment: `first` returns `nil` on empty and `where` never returns `nil` ⇒ `@services = [@user.services.where(active: true).first || @user.services.build(active: true)]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: great comment, feel free to write it as an answer.

Comment: The answer is “precedence table” and you just gave it; this is a tiny improvement, that does not deserve it’s own answer.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `@user.services.find_or_initialize_by(active: true)`?